# Why the space complexity is o(n! ) it should be linear because depth of recursive tree is o(n)

Tags: java, data-structures, permutation

```
void permute(String str, int l, int r) { 
    if (l == r) 
        System.out.println(str); 
    else { 
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) { 
            str = swap(str,l,i); 
            permute(str, l+1, r); 
            str = swap(str,l,i); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

It will take linear time complexity to print one permutation which is the depth of recursive tree.

Comment: Can you explain in detail because in first loop there will be n calls so recursive stack is taking n space but then those calls will be ended and now the recursive stack is empty end now next iteration will begin and take n-1 space so the maximum size of recursive stack is n. So I am confused?

Comment: Who said the space complexity is O(n!)?

Answer (score 0):

But `permute` is being called inside the `for` loop:

- `n` times on first call;
- `n-1` times on second call (total `n * (n-1)` );
- `n-2` times on next recursive level (`n * (n-1) * (n-2)`)
- ...
- one time on last level (`n!`)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Java and that Java `String`s are immutable ones, then each time you call `permute` you are constructing 2 more new strings:

```
str = swap(str,i,l);
...
str = swap(str,l,i);
```

Thus you construct as many strings as you are calling `permute`, then O(n!). It may happens that the garbage collector recycles unused ones, but as you can't really control GC, in the worst case nothing will be recycled.

Your space complexity is related to the way you manage the space.

If you want linear space you must use Java `StringBuffer` which provides mutable strings.

In general, printing is not counted in the space complexity (see [does-space-complexity-analysis-usually-include-output-space](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83574/does-space-complexity-analysis-usually-include-output-space)), so the fact that your implementation uses O(n!) space complexity is due to the internals of your implementation (here immutable `String`s).

Answer (score 0):

To get 'O(n)' space complexity, you have to use **a mutable** array, because in java `String` is **an immutable** object.

```java
public static String permute(String str) {
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    permute(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    return new String(arr);
}

private static void permute(char[] arr, int l, int r) {
    //...
}
```